# How do i animate the position of an element

Tags: jquery

I have a this jquery

```
var total_height = $(window).height();
var element_top = $(".box").position().top;
var element_height = $('.box').outerHeight(true);

if((element_top + element_height)>total_height){
 $(".box").css('top', (total_height - element_height));
}
```

This moves the element from off the screen to on the screen, but i want to animate this...any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [animate from jquery](http://api.jquery.com/animate)

```
$('.box').animate({ top: (total_height - element_height),}, duration );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call jQuery's [`animate` method](http://api.jquery.com/animate).